# Валидация с помощью Expression language

Tags: symfony, symfony3

Есть 3 поля, хочу провалидировать так что если 1 доступно, 2 других не доступны и наоборот. Вроде бы такое можно сделать с помощью Expression Language,но чет не получается.
Пока пробую так:

```
this.getOrganization() === \AppBundle\Entity\Organization\Organization
```

Comment: Речь о валидации при помощи Validation component?

Comment: нет, валидация с помощью Expression
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html

Comment: Да, валидация при помощи Validation component. (`Expression` constarint - часть компонента Validation) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать вот такое выражение:

```
(this.getFoo() != null) xor (this.getBar() != null and this.getBaz() != null)
```